# How can run MFTF in parallel?

Tags: mftf

Is it possibe to run MFTF in parallel? If yes, could you guide me or show me documens related that?

Thanks All

Comment: Like this you mean https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/mtf/features/parallel_execution.html but with MFTF? I see you raised a git issue https://github.com/magento/magento2-functional-testing-framework/issues/378 be interested to see if anyone replies

Comment: That's correct. I found this link: https://devdocs.magento.com/mftf/docs/commands/mftf.html#generatetests but after i generated a list of test groups as document said, i don't know how to run them in parallel.